# Error Import awswrangler: AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'connection'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that uses the lib awswrangler. Today my scrpit started to give errors in the import of the library and I don't know what is happening.
I'm running the script in a docker container with image python: 3.8

Example:

```
import awswrangler as wr

print(wr.__version__)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/avec/automation/TaskBaseUserPass.py", line 1, in <module>
    from awswrangler.pandas import Pandas
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awswrangler/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from awswrangler.pandas import Pandas  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awswrangler/pandas.py", line 45, in <module>
    class Pandas:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awswrangler/pandas.py", line 273, in Pandas
    def _read_csv_once_remote(send_pipe: mp.connection.Connection, session_primitives: "SessionPrimitives",
AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'connection'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been experienced the same issue today when trying to import awswrangler. For me, downgrading the following dependencies helped:

```
pip install fsspec==0.6.3 PyAthena==1.10.2 s3fs==0.4.0
```

It seems that one or more of them were causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If your code uses `multiprocessing.connection.Listener` or `multiprocessing.connection.Client`, then you should use:

```
import multiprocessing.connection
```

If you just use

```
import multiprocessing
```

.. then your code might get an ImportError or not. It depends on other modules. If an other module imports `multiprocessing.connection`, then it will work.

But I guess you don't want random behavior, and that's why you should import `multiprocessing.connection`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run version 3.6, the library has a problem with mp.connection.Connection in current python versions