# Unable to properly install awswrangler on conda python 3.8 env (Connection Issue)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, aws-data-wrangler

Here is the process I've followed so far.

Create Env:

```
conda create -n py38 python=3.6 anaconda
```

Install `awswrangler`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge awswrangler
```

When I go into my notebook and try to import it into my notebook, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'connection'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Import awswrangler: AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'connection'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60907299/error-import-awswrangler-attributeerror-module-multiprocessing-has-no-attrib)

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading the following dependencies:

`pip install fsspec==0.6.3 PyAthena==1.10.2 s3fs==0.4.0`